# What is the most appropriate distance measure for e-commerce data (explained in details below) to apply nearest neighbour algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, distance, nearest-neighbor, knn

I have a dataset of e-commerce website. The data is arranged in a matrix where number of rows are same as number of transactions (set of products bought) and number of columns is same as total number of products available on the website. Thus each `[i, j]` cell of a matrix is either `1` if product `j` was bought in transaction `i` or `0` otherwise. Now when a new transaction comes, I want to find k nearest neighbours for this transaction. What would be the most appropriate measure for such data? e.g. even if data is binary `(1/0)`, hamming distance won't make any sense.